# Supervisor seldom responds to my emails

Tags: communication

My old supervisor retired and this lady, who has previously ignored many of my emails, is my new supervisor.

I work remotely and usually with most co-workers I do get replies.  For example, when I send or upload a file I get a response to let me know that the file was received. This lady, in the past, would seldom let me know that she got something I sent.  One time I politely asked her if she would please let me know once the file was received.  She ignored this and I just decided at that point to accept that I would not be able to expect a reply from her.

The problem now is that I must turn in my time sheet to her and I did not get paid last pay period, and since she ignored the time sheet I sent her today, I am worried I will not be paid again. Would it be wrong for me to contact the lady who does payroll and ask her if my hours were turned in to her?

---

[Edit in from below]

Thanks for the replies. I will contact payroll tomorrow to see if my hours were turned in. I agree that this could just be an innocent mistake on the part of payroll. It would just be nice if the new supervisor would acknowledge my messages and then I wouldn't need to fret.

Comment: If you have not been paid, instantly phone and email every senior member of the company.

Comment: The important part here isn't that your boss is ignoring your email, but that you didn't get paid last week. I would raise the alarm everywhere until this is resolved immediately. You're there to make money, right? Not chat with your boss lady.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you have two issues: you are afraid you won't be paid, and you're not getting adequate feedback when you communicate by email.

For the first issue, yes, it's appropriate to contact payroll to verify that you're going to get paid.  If you have time to let your manager know ahead of time, that would be good.

> Hey Manager-  Because my pay was late the last pay period, could you verify that my timecard was submitted?  If you don't get a chance to respond, I'll contact payroll myself and check.  Thanks!

However, your bigger issue is that it doesn't seem like email is the right way to communicate with her.  And you need to talk to her about that.  Find out how she would like you to communicate, what works best for her.  You may have to adjust the way you work, but if you get the feedback you need using a different communication method, then it is what you should do.  I would initiate this conversation with a phone call or a request for a meeting, or using something other than email.

If email is really your only method, then another tack is how you write the emails.  Tell her your conclusion, what you need to do, here is the package she needs, or whatever.  And then let her know that unless you hear from her, this task is completed.  So, for instance, when you send the file, say something like this:

> Hi boss - Here is the file you requested.  Please let me know if any changes are needed.  If I don't hear from you by Friday evening, then I'll mark it as completed.  Thanks!

In other words: give her the work, give her a time to respond, and let her know your interpretation if you don't get a response.

Comment: +1 for asking for response AND telling her your interpretation for if you don't get a response

Answer (score 10):

You have not been paid. You escalate this by emailing both your manager and her manager as well as the payroll staff. If you don't receive an acceptable response within a day, you keep escalating until you do (CEO-level if necessary).

Let me be clear - you have been deeply wronged. If pay is still not forthcoming you contact your lawyer.

Granted, this could very well be an innocent mistake - I think we have all been in a position where an oversight occurred or there was an issue with the bank, and normally this would be corrected very quickly, so there's no need to burn bridges initially.

Comment: Good point that it might be some kind of mistake / oversight.  And probably best to approach it that way.  Payroll should be pretty understanding about an employee being concerned about missing pay, **if** they approach isn't combative.

Answer (score 1):

Although not specifically related to your issue regarding being paid, I have found in the past that stating a default action if no response is heard will either generate a response, or provide cover if there is a future issue.  Something like:

Dear xxxxx,

With regards issue x, pending a response from you on day y I will proceed by doing z.

regards . . .